# How can I retain my Firefox profile's cache with Geckodriver?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I need to retain my cache with Selenium and `Geckodriver`. I have a Firefox profile and I load it upon startup of `Geckodriver`:

```
ProfilesIni profilesIni = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profilesIni.getProfile("profile-name");
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

This works as it is meant to, but it does **not** copy the cache. Going to `about:cache`, it's empty. I want to retain my cache, I want to use my profile directly. Currently `Selenium/Geckodriver` copies part of the profile and uses that, but not the cache.

How am I able to keep my cache when using `Geckodriver`?

Comment: What is your _usecase_ exactly? What are you going to do with the `cache`? Relevant HTML and your code trials please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution.

Loading the profile using this does not work:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profilesIni.getProfile("profile-name");
```

For me, this did however work:

```
String profilePath = "C\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\myprofile";
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilePath));
```

I now have my correct, full cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using existing custom Firefox profile with this code (to be complete):

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
options.setProfile(selenium_profile);

options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

and my cache "grows" normaly.

If zero cache persists, check the setting of the Firefox profile (delete cache when closing).