# This code of python is working very slow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, screenshot

I am trying to get the screenshot of the below URLs through the use of selenium but when I run this code it runs very very very slow.

The most amazing thing is it sometimes runs normal but most of the times it runs very slow. so I need a help.

I just print the screenshots and URL into the HTML file. So don't Confuse.

```
waybackurls401 = {}
waybackurls403 = {}

webarchive_urls403 = []
webarchive_urls403.append('https://web.archive.org/web/2012062112352/http://xx.com/')
webarchive_urls403.append('https://web.archive.org/web/2012062112352/http://xx2.com/')  
print "\t[~]Findind of 403 staruscode urls\n"   

GEckodriver = 'F:/geckodriver.exe' 

firefox_options = Options()  
firefox_options .add_argument("-headless")  
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GEckodriver, firefox_options = firefox_options ) 

for x in webarchive_urls403:
    
    try:
    
        print "\t", x
        driver.get(x)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(6)
        imgfilename = x.split('web')[-1]
        newfile= imgfilename.replace('/', '.') +'.png'
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(newfile)
        value = "<td><img src= file:///F:/master/{0} +  width='20%' height= '25%'></td>".format(newfile, x)
        key = "<tr><td width=\"50%\">{0}</td><td width=\"50%\"><img src= file:///F:/master/{1} width='30%' height= '20%'><br><a href=\"{2}\">URL</a></td></tr>".format(x, newfile, x)
        waybackurls403[key] = value
        
    except TimeoutException as ex:  
        print "Can't take screenshot because. Timeout." 
driver.quit()
```

**EDIT:-**

According to the Kiril comment, I made some change to see where it actually stops.

```
for x in webarchive_urls403:
    print time.time()-start
    try:
    
        print "\t", x
        print 'test122'
        driver.get(x)
        print 'test1'
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        
        imgfilename = x.split('web')[-1]
        newfile= imgfilename.replace('/', '.') +'.png'
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(newfile)
        print 'test2'
        value = "<td><img src= file:///F:/AutoRecon-master/{0} +  width='20%' height= '25%'></td>".format(newfile, x)
        key = "<tr><td width=\"50%\">{0}</td><td width=\"50%\"><img src= file:///F:/AutoRecon-master/{1} width='30%' height= '20%'><br><a href=\"{2}\">URL</a></td></tr>".format(x, newfile, x)
        waybackurls403[key] = value
        print 'test3'
    except TimeoutException as ex:  
        print ex
    
    

driver.quit()
```

Now as you can see I provide some random prints for ex. `print test122` to see where it actually stuck.

And I found that I can print `test122` but not print `test1` after the `driver.get()` set it means the code is stuck after the `driver.get()`

Now that's the whole problem.

Comment: For only four URLs it takes 166 secs. Which is really slow.

Comment: interesting choice to put firefox geckodriver into `CHROMEDRIVER` variable... Did oyu time where slowness happens? e.g. is it 1 - loading driver; 2 - loading page; 3 - screenshot itself; 4 - all of the above? lso is it any faster if you run your test interactively in IDE?

Comment: Hi kiril, I made some changes in my code. Also change `driver.close()` to `driver.quit()`. Now asking you is this piece of code is correct or not?

Comment: Hi @KirilS. Looking for your reply. I have given you all the info. Thanks

Comment: If anything you want then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: if `driver.get()` takes long, it means the page loads for a long time. It could be your network, browser, or any other number of causes, but not anything you could fix directly in your code. BTW you set `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)` after getting the page, which is a bit too late, rather set it before the loop, after loading driver. So 2 things: 1 - Does it load for equally long time if you load it manually? 2 - I would pause the test and look at browser's network tab to see what is taking long time (e.g. DNS resolution...etc)

Comment: `Blocked:
→ 0 ms
DNS resolution:
→ 0 ms
Connecting:
→ 0 ms
TLS setup:
→ 0 ms
Sending:
→ 0 ms
Waiting:
→ 3752 ms
Receiving:
→ 3 ms` This was all the info.

Comment: Hi, I just replaced driver set timeout out of the loop but now I can't take any screenshots? I GOT exceptions for TIMEOUT. What does that mean.?

Comment: Exception for timeout means page loading took more than 10 seconds. Now your other test tells us that page itself should take ~4 sec. (which is not great, but does not explain 10 sec. timeout either). So next question is: what takes the remaining 6+ seconds? One options is that page loads resources (images, etc). Second option is that page is dynamic and selenium is having hard time figuring out when it was loaded.

Comment: So what I would try next is to load EXISTING profile which will already have all the resources for this page cached (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324736/how-can-i-retain-my-firefox-profiles-cache-with-geckodriver). And see if that improves timing. Also still worth understanding why getting response from server takes almost 4 seconds - it's a long time for modern network.

Comment: Hi @KirilS. I have a new question so Can you please suggest me something on that.  Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642992/how-to-run-a-function-so-it-works-also-when-other-functions-work

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, like your site just takes long to load. You could try following:

- Check if you have a bad connection//use LAN instead of Wlan
- Load your page threaded ( at `driver.get()` ), and carry on, even if the page isn't loaded yet fully.
- in case you use e free or cheap proxy, consider buying a faster one.